# Simple expression for this sum?

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Is there any simple expression for the sum:
$$
S = \sum_{n = 0}^{N-1} \frac{1}{a + e^{2 \pi i n / N}}
$$
where $ N $ is a positive integer and $ a $ is some real number. It feels to me like there should be, but I am unable to find it. Similarly, any formula for
$$
P = \prod_{n=0}^{N-1} \left( a + e^{2 \pi i n / N} \right)
$$
would be useful since $ S = \frac{d}{da} \log P $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  The roots of $x^N - 1$ are the $N$-th roots of unity, so $$x^N-1 = \prod_{n=0}^{N-1} (x -  e^{2 \pi i n / N}).$$  To get the plus sign, replace $x$ with $-x$:  $$(-x)^N -1 = \prod_{n=0}^{N-1} (-x -  e^{2 \pi i n / N}) = (-1)^n\prod_{n=0}^{N-1} (x +  e^{2 \pi i n / N}) .$$  This means $P = a^n -1$ if $n$ is even, or $a^n +1$ if $n$ is odd.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I posted the wrong question and the formula I really want is slightly different. Thank you anyway.